# Hover on circle to increase size and text increases as well

Tags: html, css, svg

I am currently drawing a svg circle from a database and it's label (text). I want the stroke width of the circle to increase on hover of the circle as well as it's text at the same time, meaning if the circle is hovered on and it's stroke width increases the size of the text should increase as well. Would I need to create a subclass in css, I am new at this..............................................

```
<circle class="circles"cx=',row[1],' cy=',row[2],' r="0.2"></circle>
<text class="text" x=',row[1],'y=',row[2],' transform="translate(0',move,')scale(-1,1) rotate(180)">',row[0],'</text>')       

.text {
font-size: 0.8px;
font-family: Verdana;
fill: peachpuff;
}

.text:hover {
font-size: 2px;
}   

.circles{
        fill:       cyan;


}
.circles:hover{
        stroke:       cyan;
        stroke-width:   0.4; 
 }
```

Comment: are you trying to scale the circle?

Comment: No, I just need the text to increase in size, onhover of the circle

Comment: @lloyd Make sure to accept the answer if it solved your query.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a demonstration:**

- Wrap your circle and text in a single SVG container or seperate classes as per the requirement.
- Use the `stroke-width` attribute of circle and `font-size` for the text, and change their values accordingly on hover of the container.

```css
.circleS:hover circle{
stroke-width:5;
}
.circleS:hover text{
font-size:18px;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100" class="circleS">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <text x="25" y="50" fill="white">Random</text>
</svg>
```